# Python extract n sentences from string after the first instance of the string has been found

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

I would like to extract the first instance where the element in the list 'words' is found. My code below is doing this correctly.
However for some items in the list 'words' such as dog and cat, I want to extract the first occurance of the string, but also the 3 sentences after that - please can someone show how I can do this?

My code below:

```
text= 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. she has a kitten. cat is cute. the dog want want want was there. my dog is a puppy. chocolate brownies. flower power.'

words=['dog', 'chocolate', 'cat' ,'flower']
lst=[]

for j in words:
    for i in text.split('.'):
        if j in i:
            lst.append (i.split('.')[0]) 
            break
else:
    None
     
print(lst)
```

Desired output:

```
['the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best' , 'chocolate brownies', 'the cat is there too. python is the best. she has a kitten', 'flower power']
```

What I have tried (indexing) - not sure what im doing incorrectly

```
if j[0] in i:
 lst.append( i.split('.')[0:3]
if j[2] in i:
 lst.append. i.split('.')[0:3]
```

Thank you

Comment: you want the sentence i where the word is found, or you want the first sentence (0), if you find the word?

Comment: I want the first sentence where the word is found, and then for some elements, find the first sentence+ extract 3 sentences after that

Comment: @qwerty12 How do you determine which elements should extract 3 sentences afterwards? Unless you know this, it is impossible to do what you're asking for in a single for loop.

Comment: yep so in the example its dog and cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extracting the first instance, your code does work but has some unnecessary code.

Simply append `i`, not `i.split('.')[0]`. Your `i` is already splitted.

```
for j in words:
    for i in text.split('.'):
        if j in i:
            lst.append(i) 
            break
```

Now for extracting n sentences,

```
for j in words:
    for index, i in enumerate(text.split('.')):
        if j in i:
            if j == "dog" or j == "cat":
               lst.append('.'.join(text.split('.')[index:index+n]))
            else:
               lst.append(i) 
            break
```

Here using enumerate, we track the index of the sentences. If we encounter a sentence with dog or cat, instead of appending we add the sublist with length n.

Comment: thank you! Exactly what I am after. Would it be possible to append the dog outputs  as only one long element in the list, same for the cat outputs too -currently its than 3 different elements in the list? Reason being is that I am appending to a dataframe with set column names - thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean one long element?

Comment: so put it into one long string, rather than diff elements: example output: `output=['the dog was there. dog. the cat is there too', ' chocolate brownies', ' the cat is there too.python is the best.cat has a kitten']`

Answer (score 0):

**Task 1**: split the paragraph, you get a list of sentences. for each query word in the list words, check if it exist in the list of sentences, if yes add it to the result.

```
text= 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. she has a kitten. cat is cute. the dog want want want was there. my dog is a puppy. chocolate brownies. flower power.'

words=['dog', 'chocolate', 'cat' ,'flower']

lst=[]

list_sentences = text.split('.')

for query_word in words:
    for sentence in list_sentences:
        if query_word in sentence:
            lst.append (sentence) 
            break
else:
    None
     
print(lst)
```

**important note** : your code work, but it is wrong, because you have a sentence i, so you append it directly, in your code you tray to split it `lst.append(i.split('.')[0])` and because the sentence i doesn't contain **'.'**, you have the same result at the end.

**Task 2**: is your second task when you append all the three sentences. exactly the same code, just add all the three sentences beginning from the one where the query word is found. We use enumerate to track the indices.

```
text= 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. she has a kitten. cat is cute. the dog want want want was there. my dog is a puppy. chocolate brownies. flower power.'

words=['dog', 'chocolate', 'cat' ,'flower']

list_sentences = text.split('.')

list_task2 = []
query_word = words[0] # just example, you can change it

for i, sentence in enumerate(list_sentences):
        if query_word in sentence:
            #list_task2.append (list_sentences[i:i+3])
            list_task2 = list_task2 + list_sentences[i:i+3]
            break
print(list_task2)
```